# ASP.NET/CSS - can't get a:active to work

Tags: asp.net, css

i have a menu bar in my master page that is made up of 4 hyperlinks with background images that are being set using css. on hover-over, these images are swapped out, also by css. so each menu item (hyperlink) has two images, a static image and a hover-over image. when a user clicks one of the menu items and is taken to that page, i would like that hover-over image to "stick" for that page. here's my code:

```
<div id="nav">
    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlHome" runat="server" 
            NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" CssClass="menuHome" />
</div>

 #nav a, #nav a:visited
{
    height:39px;
    border:none;
    padding:0;
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
}

a.menuHome, a.menuHome:visited
{
    width:76px;
    height:39px;
    background:url('home.gif');
}

a.menuHome:hover, a.menuHome:active
{
    width:76px;
    height:39px;
    background:url('home_hover.gif') no-repeat;
}
```

my hyperlinks background images are rendering, the mouse-over effect works too, i just can't get the mouse-over image to "stick"/stay active. any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, (and I feel there are sure to be better ones) would be to have an additional class, maybe `activepage` and then add this class to the active menu item on each page.
You could try doing it dynamically on Page Load. This `activepage` class could have a css entry that includes `background:url('home_hover.gif') no-repeat;`

Just in case you weren't aware, multiple class identifiers can be set on a single html element by separating with a space eg: `<a href="foo.html" class="activepage menuHome">`